# Calculations across multiple fields SQL

Tags: sql

[Output]

[image: 1]

**strong text**

I want to calculate the balance, but not sure in how to do it across the multiple records.

```
"SELECT FORMAT(Date,'yyyy/MM/dd'), Reference, Description, Debit, Credit, (-------) as Balance 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE Id='ID' AND Date> 2022-01-01"
```

How would I change this to calculate the balance over all the fields?

Comment: tag your database as well

Comment: what's your desired output? show an example for a calculation you're trying to make

Comment: `SUM(CREDIT - DEBIT)` and `GROUP BY` your key field

Comment: How are you going to define the order of the rows?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, sum(coalesce(Credit,-Debit)) over (order by date rows unbounded preceding) as Balance
from t
```

| Date | Reference | Description | Debit | Credit | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 00:00:00.000 |  | Balance Brought Forward |  | 3450.93 | 3450.93 |
| 2022-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 8 | CSOS | 25.70 |  | 3425.23 |
| 2022-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 22-Jun | Elec 26082/26630 | 1041.72 |  | 2383.51 |
| 2022-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 8 | Monthly Levies | 1785.01 |  | 598.50 |
| 2022-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 8 | Sewer | 598.44 |  | 0.06 |
| 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 21-Jul | Elec 26630/26967 | 679.68 |  | -679.62 |
| 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 9 | CSOS | 25.70 |  | -705.32 |
| 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 9 | Sewer | 598.44 |  | -1303.76 |
| 2022-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 9 | Monthly Levies | 1785.01 |  | -3088.77 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ad5c4de493a3df9be6b163861632c62&hide=1)